# Powershell - read list and output gwmi contents to separate file

Tags: scripting, wmi, powershell-2.0

I am trying to use WMI to get the hostname, IP and MAC address from all computers in the domain and store them in a text file.
When I run my code, I receive the following error:

```
gwmi : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)>
At line:10 char:13
+     $base = gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration -computername $comp | where { ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

If I run gwmi against an individual machine, it works fine. I can get the information I need

This script fails with the above error:

```
$computers = Get-Content -path F:\scripts\domain_computers.txt  
foreach ($comp in $computers) {  
$base = gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration -computername $comp | where {$_.dnsdomain -eq "mydomain.com"}
$machine = $base.DNSHostName   
$mac = $base.MACAddress  
$ip = $base.IPAddress  
Write-Output "<$comp>`n`tname = $machine'n</$comp>" | Out-File F:\scripts\comp_list_test.txt -Append
}
```

The `write-ouput` is just for testing. I would want to print all variables once working. What am I missing?

EDIT:

The text file domain_computers.txt has each computername on a separate line. No spaces or trailing characters.
I also figured out that the script was working properly. It was failing on the machines that did not have WinRM enabled. When I was testing on individual computers, I just happened to test on the ones that had WinRM enabled.

I now have another issue with this script but will post it in a new question, since it is not related to this.

Comment: this is probably a better question for http://serverfault.com

Comment: Is there a way to migrate this question over or should I just ask a new question there?

Comment: I'll flag it for migration

Comment: What does the content of `F:\scripts\domain_computers.txt` look like?

Comment: I second @alroc, it would help if you provided an example of the content of **domain_computers.txt**, so we wouldn't have to speculate about what's going on in there. BTW, I think this question does belong at stackoverflow. It's about coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the script was working properly. It was failing on the machines that did not have WinRM enabled. When I was testing on individual computers, I just happened to test on the ones that had WinRM enabled.

Comment: That was my first thought, but if that's the case you get the error multiple times (once for each computer that doesn't have WinRM running), and your description implied that you were getting just the one error. That's why I guessed that gwmi might be trying to access one nonexistent computer whose name is an agglomeration of the names of all of the computers. You need to be more complete in your descriptions. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does **domain_computers.txt** by any chance contain a comma-separated list? If you're getting only one error, rather than an error for each iteration of the loop, it sounds like the file is being read as a single string, which implies that it doesn't have line breaks. Either place each computer name on a separate line, or split the contents into an array like this:

```
$computers = (Get-Content -path F:\scripts\domain_computers.txt) -split ','
```

Use `-split ', '` if there are spaces after the commas, or `-split ' '` if they're just separated by spaces.